# Hyperlinks are gone, can't open in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the most part my script works, which is to find links, then insert a copy of the links in a new element. I can't seem to get them to be hyperlinks and have them open in a new window/tab.

Thanks for any help!

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('<h2>TEST LINKS:</h2>').appendTo($("div").last());
        $('div').find('a').each(function () {
            var $attr = $(this).clone();
            $('div').last().append($(this).html() + "<br>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you assign the variable `$attr` and then never use it?

Comment: Oops my fault. A left over after trying to use other ways I've seen online. I tried this way but hit the same wall.       $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $('<h2>TEST LINKS:</h2>').appendTo($("div").last());
    $.each($("a").clone(), function(k,v){
      $('div').last().append($(this).html() + "<br>");
    });
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('<h2>TEST LINKS:</h2>').appendTo($("div").last());
        $('div').find('a').each(function () {
            $('div').last().append($(this).clone(), "<br>");
        });
    });
});
```

You need to comma separate items using append if you want to keep them as objects. Try that.